# Cordova + Android - android-windowSoftInputMode adjustPan not working

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 5.4.0 and I have this in my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
```

but after building, in my `AndroidManifest.xml` there still is

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Why is it not working? And how can I solve it?

Comment: could u explain bit more ?

Comment: It seems like the <preference in config.xml is not propagated in the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml. I am currently having this issue has well.

Comment: Same here, even with Cordova 6.1.1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `android-windowSoftInputMode` preference seems to be supported by [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#android-windowSoftInputMode) only, not Cordova.

**Workaround 1 (Cordova 6.4+): use [edit-config](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config)**

Make sure the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` namespace attribute is included in the `widget` element and add an edit-config element:

```
<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>
    ...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="merge">
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</widget>
```

**Workaround 2 (prior to Cordova 6.4): use a plugin**

Add the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Add the following preference:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
    ...
</platform>
```

**Workaround 3: add a before_build hook**

Add the following [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) to config.xml:

```
<hook type="before_build" src="scripts/appBeforeBuild.js" />
```

Add a file appBeforeBuild.js to the scripts directory with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var pathToManifest = path.join(__dirname, '../platforms/android', 'AndroidManifest.xml');
if(fs.existsSync(pathToManifest)) {
    var config = fs.readFileSync(pathToManifest, 'utf8');

    var result = config.replace(/(android:windowSoftInputMode=").*?(")/, '$1adjustPan$2');
    fs.writeFileSync(pathToManifest, result, 'utf8');

    console.log('Set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan');
}
else {
    console.log('Could not find AndroidManifest to set android:windowSoftInputMode');
}
```

This script will use Node to lookup the AndroidManifest and do a regex replace on the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute (first occurrence only).

Comment: What is the differences between PhoneGap and Cordova? Except one is Adobe proprietary and other Apache open source?

Comment: Great answer, put me on the right track. Although it didn't work for me until I used the module approach found [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/#sample-usage) and it took me a second to realize the `scripts` directory everyone suggests would go at the same level as your `config.xml`

Comment: @PhilipBijker: I have tried your solution but it doesn't works quite well for me. Can I ask you that adding this script would no longer take in consideration the setting that will be set on `config.xml` file ? I've checked to logs and its printed that it has been replaced. Any clue?

Comment: @el.severo That's correct. This answer won't look at any value set in `config.xml`. It will just set the input mode to `adjustPan`.

Comment: @PhilipBijker: Ok. Thank you! Still have a question: Have you done any specific config in app.config / config.xml ? Could your share some snippets on github (gist) or a sample project.

Comment: See also this thread, removing the StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true); answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934689/phonegap-android-keyboard-covers-input-elements-scrolling-is-disabled

Answer (score 8):

I found a simple solution using the [`edit-config`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) tag which is built into cordova since v6.4.0. My `config.xml` now looks like this and the keyboard no longer resizes the viewport!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <!-- ... -->
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </edit-config>
    <!-- ... -->
</widget>
```

*Hint*: When experimenting to get this working, I made some accidental changes to my `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can reset this easily be removing and re-adding the android platform to your cordova project like so: `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android`.

Comment: Works. I had to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` (which you added also) because I only copied the `<edit-config>` part at first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

1. Index.html

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">
   ```
2. config.xml

   ```
   <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize|adjustPan" />
   ```

Comment: by `adjustResize|adjustPan`, are you trying to say that the value can be either of the two, or is `adjustResize|adjustPan` the literal value of the `android-windowSoftInputMode` preference ? I would be surprised if it could hold both values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are changing the wrong AndroidManifest.xml.
In your application, under \platform\android... you will find the .xml file, you have to change that one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12746971)

Comment: @NitzanTomer why it is not an answer? That happened to me too, i was changing the wrong AndroidManifest. Then i realized that the one i was changing it is generated automatically by the correct AndroidManifest file which is supposed to change..And that is the answer. Thank you

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

and add this to your `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
   <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a problem with using `display: flex` for the container of the inputs. Changing the CSS so the container was not flexbox based solved the keyboard / input / scroll interaction problem on Android for me.