# The ionic-plugin-keyboard doesn't fire events on Android

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, cordova-plugins

I have the next test code:

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><button>Show keyboard</button></p>
    <p><input></input></p>
    <p><span>?</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", handler, false);
function handler() {
  window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "showed";
  });
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
  });
}
```

The `show()` function works, and I understand that the plugin is available from my app. But when the keyboard is showed nothing occurs: my `span` tag doesn't get the `"showed"` text.

What is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Android, add `<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />` to config.xml as noted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683935/5356747

With this preference set keyboard events started to fire in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have added **cordova-plugin-keyboard** (its events doesn't fire on android. Plus, the name of events are also different).
You need to add **ionic-plugin-keyboard**:

`cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard --save`

Comment: Do you need BOTH plugins (the Cordova & the Ionic one)? Or just the Ionic one?